# How to use IS NULL in H2 database

Tags: h2

I have table ABC in H2 defined as

```
CREATE TABLE ABC 
(
  A int,
  B varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  C varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I would like to run a query:

```
Select * 
from ABC 
where C IS NULL;
```

Expected Result: All the values where C is null.
Obtained Result: No values at all, only the table structure.
It works when  I use `where C='null'`

How can I use the IS NULL in H2. I tried by setting
url as jdbc:h2:mem:configurations;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL. It didn't work as expected.The query works fine with Postgres I am also using Postgres.

Comment: Then my guess is that you aren't actually storing any `NULL` values in the `C` column, but rather the string `'null'`.

Comment: yeah....Thank you....How could I miss this... Its like...I was fetching values from postgres table and then is inserted to h2 so as to maintain in memory database. The null is 'null value' in postgres and when I put it into h2 I was making it as string...